# pandas dataframe export row column value

Tags: pandas, csv

I import data from Excel into python pandas with read_clipboard.

```
   import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

The column index are the month (januar, februar, ...,december). The row index are products name (orange, banana, etc). And the value in cells are the monthly sales.

How can I export a csv of the following format

```
month;product;sales
```

To make it more visual, I show the input in the first image and how the output shoud be in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: any reason why `pd.read_clipboard` instead of `pd.read_excel` ? (something like: `pd.read_excel('your_excel_file', sheet_name='whatever').to_csv('output.csv', columns=['month', 'product', 'sales'], index=False, sep=';')` ?

Comment: yes, because it s a excel file but I use libreoffice.

Comment: If you've got openpyxl and xlrd installed you can read excel directly if it's actually an Excel file - nevermind if you're opening it in libreoffice...

Comment: but maybe, let's forget about the way to import. Let's suppose I have a pandas dataframe named df. In such case, how to achieve my aim. In other words. I have the variable df which is a dataframe. In such case how do I proceed?

Comment: Like I said above: `df.to_csv('output.csv', columns=['month', 'product', 'sales'], index=False, sep=';')` ?

Comment: But this is not working it says KeyError: "None of [['month', 'product', 'sales']] are in the [columns]".  My column index are called 'january' 'february' ... 'december' and my products are called 'apple' banana' etc....

Comment: Ahhh... okay - so can you produce some sample data... looks like you probably want to pivot or stack... it'd be easier to visualise the means to get to your end result with some sample input data.

Comment: I just added a picture to make it clear...

Comment: Easier if you show a `.head(20).to_dict()` from your DF so people can copy paste it and work with it...

Comment: you probably want to look at: [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it thanks to your advice : using unstack

```
df2 = df.transpose()
df3 = df2 =.unstack()
df3.to_csv('my/path/name.csv', sep=';')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use xlrd package.
Sample Book1.xlsx:

```
        january february    march
Orange     4       2         4
banana     2       6         3
apple      5       1         7
```

sample code:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("Book1.xlsx")

print(book.sheet_names())

first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
row1 = first_sheet.row_values(0)

print(first_sheet.nrows)

for i in range(len(row1)):
    if i !=0:
        next_row = first_sheet.row_values(i)
        for j in range(len(next_row)-1):
                print("{};{};{}".format(row1[i],next_row[0],next_row[j+1]))
```

Result:

```
january;Orange;4.0
january;Orange;2.0
january;Orange;4.0
february;banana;2.0
february;banana;6.0
february;banana;3.0
march;apple;5.0
march;apple;1.0
march;apple;7.0
```

Comment: nice answer, you can start using pandas'

Answer (score 0):

If that is only the case, it might solve that problem:

```
month = df1.columns.to_list()*3
product = []
sales=[]
for x in range(0,2):
    product += [df1.index[x]]*12
    sales += df1.iloc[x].values.tolist()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': month, 'product': product, 'sales': sales})
```

But you need to look for smarter way if you have a larger Dataframe, like what @Jon Clements suggested in the comment.

Comment: Hum thanks that looks interesting but it's still to manual i cant write all my products manually...

Comment: Then use `df1.index[index_number]` to get the name